# conda command not found. The .profile and "echo $PATH" seem however okay

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, .profile

I've blindly installed numerous times Python, admittedly without fully knowing what I was installing and where. I figured that now before I encounter even more problems that I need to tidy up my environment a bit. In Terminal, I used the command `which -a python` and came up with this:

```
/opt/local/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
~/anaconda/bin/python
/opt/local/bin/python
/opt/local/bin/python
/opt/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

My `.profile` has:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib/gmt4/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="~/teqc:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/runpkr000:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
##
# Your previous ~/.profile file was backed up as ~/.profile.macports-saved_2015-04-02_at_16:40:23
##
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-04-02_at_16:40:23: adding an appropriate
PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

And `echo $PATH` gives:

```
~/anaconda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/runpkr000:~/teqc:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib/gmt4/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:~/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin
```

I can't seem to locate where the problem is. I have been using pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy on my MBP for over a year and all seem to work fine (actually, the `import pandas` is always highlighted as red, but it works anyway). I've used Macports and Anacondas to install (as can be seen from the `which -a python`, it seems), and only just realised that only one of them was necessary to use. I'm a bit confused as to how to configure `.profile` and generally would like to tidy up this mess. My aim would be to then use `conda` to install another library (in this case `obspy`).

Answer (score 1):

I followed the suggestion at the [link](https://github.com/spacetelescope/JWSTUserTraining2016/issues/12)
Where basically he has told to install anaconda using .sh variant instead of .pkg and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi instead of reinstalling everything you may add a symlink to conda (assuming everything is fine in your .profile or .bash_profile).
I did the following and worked for me:

```
ln -s "Applications/anaconda/bin/conda" /usr/local/bin/conda
```

Hope this helps
P.S. worked on OSX